# Javascript timer loads automatically instead of on click event

Tags: javascript, function, timer

I have a JS time counter on a little game app, it works fine, but instead of beeing activated on first click (I have a firsClick variable set to true that I use on click event to invoke startTimer function ) it start as page loads and I receive error when game finishes or if I reset game with its button.
Any help or suggestion is welcomed, thank you

```
let liveTimer = 0;
//timer function
function startTimer(val) {
   return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }
   setInterval( function(){
   document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML=startTimer(++liveTimer%60);
   document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML=startTimer(parseInt(liveTimer/60,10));
}, 1000);
// stopping timer function - clears time stored in liveTimer var
function stopTimer() {
   clearInterval(liveTimer);
}
```

Comment: `return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }` The curly bracket at the end terminates the function block

Comment: If you indent your code properly you'll see what is wrong

Comment: Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition ends too early:

```
function startTimer(val) {
return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }
setInterval( function(){
document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML=startTimer(++liveTimer%60);
document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML=startTimer(parseInt(liveTimer/60,10));
}, 1000);
```

What you might have wanted to write:

```
function startTimer(val) {
    setInterval( function(){
       document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML=startTimer(++liveTimer%60);
       document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML=startTimer(parseInt(liveTimer/60,10));
    }, 1000);
    return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; 
}
```

Although I don't see what you want to do with that "val". It has nothing to do with the interval body or its call at all